# Issue with jQuery Tabs/IFrames Executing All at Once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I set up 8 tabs and 8 IFrame (1 per tab) but they all seem to be executing at the same time when my main page loads. This is an issue because each page has its own `onload` functions to run and that hangs up my main page while it waits for those pages to complete.

I want to have the IFrame run only when I click on the specific tab for it. How would I accomplish this?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            active: 0,
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

                ui.jqXHR.success(function () {
                    ui.tab.data("loaded", true);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#tabs').css('border', '');
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Embed1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed2">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed3">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed4">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed5">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed6">Page 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed7">Page 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Embed8">Page 7</a></li>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="Embed1" seamless="seamless" src="home.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed2" seamless="seamless" src="page1.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed3" seamless="seamless" src="page2.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed4" seamless="seamless" src="page3.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed5" seamless="seamless" src="page4.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed6" seamless="seamless" src="page5.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed7" seamless="seamless" src="page6.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="Embed8" seamless="seamless" src="page7.aspx" sandbox=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Iframe's (and you don't). You have to set the `src` programmatically.
Leave the `src=` attribute empty and load it with jQuery.

```
<button type="button" id="Button1">Load Iframe</button>

<iframe id="Embed1"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $("#Embed1").attr("src", "Page2.aspx")
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi vdwwd, thanks, I didn't originally want to use iframes, but when I used the tabs directly the jscript code on the href pages wouldn't execute.